# camera preview - android

Tags: android, camera

I am implementing a simple camera app and I see this in developer site:
"After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call startPreview() again first"

I am calling:

```
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
```

in surfaceDestroyed() which is called after takePicture(). I am not very sure where startPreview() should be called again in order to resume the preview.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if u want to resume the preview again you will have to start it or otherwise create a new instance of an preview, so that surface gets created again calling startPreview() again.